# Which character recognition technique is used in Android vision

Tags: google-api, computer-vision, google-play-services

I made college project using android vision api. I was wondering what technology/technique is used by Google

Answer (score 0):

As I've read the [Get Started with the Mobile Vision API - Android](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/getting-started), the example demonstrates the vision API for detecting faces and barcodes. Also, [Optical Character Recognition (OCR)](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2017#0) gives a computer the ability to read text that appears in an image, letting applications make sense of signs, articles, flyers, pages of text, menus, or any other place that text appears as part of an image. The Mobile Vision Text API gives Android developers a powerful and reliable OCR capability that works with most Android devices and won't increase the size of your app.

You may follow through this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/package-summary) which provides common functionality for working with visual object detectors.

- Barcode detector: [com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/package-summary.html)
- Face detector: [com.google.android.gms.vision.face](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/face/package-summary.html)
- Text recognizer: [com.google.android.gms.vision.text](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/text/package-summary.html)

Hope this helps!